# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in / while using retrofit 2.1.0 for GET method

Tags: java, android

I am using Retrofit2 for API parsing.

While using `retrofit1.9.0` both post and get methods work properly. But using `retrofit 2.1.0`, in the get method, there is an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /

I have checked my code and there is no problem, it's working for the post method.

```
    Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder() 
                        .baseUrl("sample.com/ecomtest/index.php?route=api/") 
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: Please remember to share some relevant code which can help people to get it solved quickly for you.

Comment: Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://sample.com/ecomtest/index.php?route=api/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

Comment: Getting exception in this code and app gets crashed

Comment: use `"sample.com/ecomtest/"` as the base url

Comment: i had tried that, my api url is "sample.com/ecomtest/index.php?route=api/login&email={email}&password={password}‌​" I am using @Path to pass parameters email and password field. but while checking there is an issue in "?route=api" is there any solution to rectify the error

Answer (score 40):

'?' can not in baseUrl, you should move it to API interface. like this.

The full url :`https://free-api.heweather.com/v5/now?
city=yourcity&key=yourkey`

so, `baseUrl = "https://free-api.heweather.com/v5/"`

and the API interface

```
@GET("now?")
Observable<HeWeather5> getNowWeather(@Query("city") String city,@Query("key") String key);
```

Comment: Nice explanation, helped me.

Comment: Why `@GET("now?")` has "?" isn't supposedly no longer needed since we already provide `@Query("city")`

Answer (score 16):

The URL you have passed as `API_BASE_URL` should end with "/" so add it at the end of your URL.

```
Retrofit.Builder builder =
         new Retrofit.Builder()
                     .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

where

```
String API_BASE_URL = "http://www.domain.com/"; //string end with "/"
```

it will work.

Comment: I have also checked this scenario but still the problem occurs

Comment: you are adding "/" after "?" in URL, that means it goes as the parameter.
"sample.com/ecomtest/" and pass route in parameter.

Comment: thanks RBK but  still the problem occurs while using it in retrofit1 it works perfectly for the same base_url="sample.com/ecomtest/index.php?route=api/"

Comment: I am facing same problem. my base URL = "sample.com/index.php/" API end point is "?route=api/getList" .... when run the app I got url like "sample.com/index.php/?route=api/getList" instead of "sample.com/index.php?route=api/getList"... :(

Answer (score 6):

In retrofit you can not use endpoints like "some?" in base URL.
Split you URL like

```
String url="http://sample.com/ecomtest/index.php?route=api/";
String baseUrl=url.split(".com/")[0]+".com/";
String queryUrl=url.split(".com")[1];
```

then use

```
Retrofit.Builder builder =
         new Retrofit.Builder()
                     .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

and pass you end point as a path to request method like

```
@GET("{endpoint}")
    Call<Response> getData(@Path("endpoint") String endpoint);
```

and done

Answer (score 5):

Suppose your url is "https://yourapi.com/abc?def&key=123"

Split your url into two parts.

```
String baseURL ="https://yourapi.com/"; //make sure you have '/' at the end

String key = "123";
```

then add rest in the GET annotation like this `@GET("abc?def&key="+key)`

Comment: You are genius, I salute your Sir

Answer (score 3):

Had the same situation and answers here almost cover/explain the solution.
However not exactly.

I tried to store `BASE_URL` like this: `sample.com/api`
And my endpoints would be for e.x: `/users`

The solution with adding `/` didn't help: `sample.com/api/`

The problem is with more than one `/` in the `BASE_URL` and I guess retrofit gets crazy about that the slash is not only as the ending mark.

The only solution that worked: `sample.com/`
And the endpoint for that would be: `api/users`
So keeping just one `/` in the BASE_URL was the solution for me, and keep it at the end of the base url string

Answer (score 0):

sure to set [encoded = false] Like This :

```
suspend fun getAnyThing(@Query("api_key", encoded = false) apikey: String)
```

Answer (score -4):

I solved this Error by using `URL = "URL/"`. There has to be / as the last character to make it work.