# OTP value sending API is working when it will executed in a browser, but not when integrated with android code

Tags: android

```
/Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: https://2factor.in/API/V1/mydrive%20otp%20activarion
```

How to solve the illegal exception in the base url?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395460/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-baseurl-must-end-in-while-using-retrofit-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in / while using retrofit 2.1.0 for GET method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395460/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-baseurl-must-end-in-while-using-retrofit-2)

Comment: AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sonalnaidu.myapplication, PID: 14026
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.sonalnaidu.myapplication.MessageResponse.getDetails()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sonalnaidu.myapplication.MainActivity$1$2.onResponse(MainActivity.java:107)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
      
how to solve this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit supports the base URL until first forward slash after `https://`

In Your case base URL must be `https://2factor.in/` this

Comment: when executing this url in android return null reference , but that url will also work in the browser. How can I rectify this problem?

Comment: Please post the exception

Comment: This does not relate to base url